# Unable to update EntityFramework models from MySQL database in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, mariadb

When I try to update my models in mydbcontext.edmx I get the following error after pressing update model from database.

```
An exception of type 'SystemArgumentException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. 
The exception message is: Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent. 
Connection string: server=localhost;port=3306;database=annotation-web;user id= root;password=12345678'
```

I have downloaded and updated my connector and I have also installed the latest MySQL from:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Initially, the wizard for updating the models would pop up, show me the option to include sensitive data in the connection string or not and then close immediately when I pressed next (No matter whichever option I picked for the connection string). I did some research and I found out my connector is the wrong version so I updated my connector. Now it tells me "Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent".

Comment: hard to say but may be a semicolon is missing between "localhost" and "port" in "server= localhostport=3306;" may be you edited the connection string manually or something?

Comment: @umberto-petrov that was my mistake in copying the error over correctly. Otherwise, it does include the ; I double-checked it. I edited my question now, thank you